# Mysql crashes in amazon linux

Tags: mysql

We are trying to drop tables from mysql that is installed in amazon linux which the os is not able to handle and is very slow, mysql crashes as well or goes to the defunct mode. We have tried to execute the same on centos5.5 but the process was very fast and the mysql did not crash. The mysql configuration are the same on both the servers. Kindly tell us why this scenario happens ??.

Comment: any error in mysql error log which could be shared? you can also look into os error log and share any relevant message..

Comment: try to stop the service and start it again, then check if the table still exist, I guess its a cache error

Answer (score -1):

Check the log file, where the error was written on disk or check in the event viewer log